# Add class active to menu links is working with links that has no extension only, how to make it find all links with and without extinctions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Using .httaccess I removed all the .php extensions from the end of any URL, for example index.php will be shown as index "site.com/index and not site.com/index.php".

Now, using the script below, I am adding a class of .active to the anchor  of the current open page.

```
//Main menu .active classes handler
    $("#mainMenu a").filter(function () {
        var _href = location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
        if (location.pathname === "/") {_href += "index";}
        return _href === this.href;
    }).addClass("active");
```

The problem is? The script above try and find page names/url without the php extension, for example, the links have to be as follows in order for it to work:

```
<li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
```

But my links are as follows, and I don't want to remove the .php extension

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

What can I do to make it find urls with php or without?
I tried adding `.php` to `var _href = location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");` thinking that is the way to do it, but it did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to retrieve the value of the with and without an extension.
Look for yourself at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp or learn it at http://regexone.com

You could also do the following.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert(filename);
```

Comment: How can I implement the last suggestion you made?